# Concept of Centre of Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, mass

I have attached a photo of a question along with its solution but I want to understand the concept behind the solution as in how did we do this?

[image]

Edit 1: I was unable to understand why both have been equated to each other in the above problem.

Comment: Be more descriptive in terms of what you understood and what not, also what approach did you take, this makes it easier for others to give precise answers.

Comment: @buddy001 thanks I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the location of the center of mass initially, and set it at exactly the same spot after the displacement of the parts, since in this case the COM is at rest.

As noted Netwon's 2nd law describes the motion of the center of mass of a system of bodies as a result of an external force, which in this case is absent. So the center of mass will not accelerate, and will remain moving with constant velocity, or be fixed in place.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you agree with the fact that the center of mass of a system never changes unless and until an external force is applied.

In this question you can see that gravitational acceleration is along the *y*-axis but along the *x*-axis there's no external force acting on it. So the ordinate of the centre of mass won't change.

Imagine that the block has come down and the wedge has been displaced by $x$ units then obviously the block has moved a distance $2.2$ units along the wedge in the *x*-axis as it has come down, but also since the wedge itself has moved a distance of $x$ units then the actual distance traversed in the *x*-axis is $2.2 - x$ now all you have to do is conserve the ordinate of the centre of mass of the system.

Comment: The thing is I am only confused in the last rest I figured out so can you please elaborate?